# How to solve libnss3 dependency conflict

Tags: 14.04, package-management, dependencies

i am using Ubuntu 14.04, i am trying to install filezilla but it seems there is a dependency issue, i tried `apt-get -f install` but again there is this dependency issue.

```
libnss3-nssdb : Depends: libnss3 (= 2:3.19.2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) but 2:3.19.2-1ubuntu1 is installed
```

these dependencies seems to be similar but yet different.

Comment: take a look at this https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2314991

Comment: trying to remove all the libnss3 for i386 gives the same output

Answer (score 1):

ok so, what i did might seem desperate.
i used the

```
# aptitude -f install
```

aptitude was be too eager to remove or downgrade large numbers of packages but it gives an option . Denial to the first suggestion , prompted a shorter fix, just what i was looking for. 
it works as

```
# apt-get -f install
```

But more efficiently.